# get variables data from functions.php to template wordpress (without global variables)

Tags: functions, variables

I have in wordpress **functions.php** file

This sample works with one variable only, but i want multiple variables

```
function variables() {
   $var1 = 'lorem';
    return $var1;
}
```

in the front template results **"lorem"**:

```
echo variables();
```

works fine, but if i have many variables how can i displayed it?

example:

```
echo variables('var1');
echo variables('var2');
echo variables('etc');
```

i found a solution using global variables, but i don't like use that.

edit:

in **functions.php** add variables :

```
$some = "lorem 1"
$some2 = "lorem 2"
$some3 = "lorem 3"
```

then display in theme

```
<?php echo some(); ?>
<?php echo some2(); ?>
<?php echo some3(); ?>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: edited, sorry please refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think into the opposite direction: Don't **pull** the variables from the template, **push** them into it. Templates should be as simple as possible, the shouldn't know anything about the content of the rest of your code, for example function names.

In other words: use hooks.

In your template:

```
// the numbers are just context examples
do_action( 'something', 'one' );
do_action( 'something', 'two' );
do_action( 'something', 'three' );
```

In your `functions.php`, you add a callback to that action:

```
// 1, 2, 3 are your variables
add_action( 'something', function( $context ) {
    switch ( $context )
    {
        case 'one':
            echo 1;
            break;
        case 'two':
            echo 2;
            break;
        case 'three':
            echo 3;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Context parameter is wrong!';
    }
});
```

You can of course also echo more than one line and do some more complex stuff in the callback handler.

Comment: thanks!!!! @fuxia i think was solved!